# Android /storage/emulated/0 and /data/media/0 different permissions

Tags: android, linux, permissions, chmod, chown

I have the LG G3 smartphone.
During filesystem exploring I spot that

/storage/emulated/0/... directory (recived from system to my local user) have permission that not allowing chmod and chown operations. When I tryed to change some file to 777 I recived 0 result and no error message but nothing happened. Total commander file manager work same way.

But when I try to change filesystem permissin directly by 
/data/media/0/... I can to do it.

/proc/sef/mounts tell me:

```
965 965 0:1 / / ro,relatime master:1 - rootfs rootfs ro
966 965 0:11 / /dev rw,nosuid,relatime master:2 - tmpfs tmpfs rw,seclabel,size=1447296k,nr_inodes=84929,mode=755
967 966 0:9 / /dev/pts rw,relatime master:3 - devpts devpts rw,seclabel,mode=600
968 966 0:17 / /dev/cpuctl rw,relatime master:4 - cgroup none rw,cpu
969 965 0:3 / /proc rw,relatime master:5 - proc proc rw
970 965 0:12 / /sys rw,relatime master:6 - sysfs sysfs rw,seclabel
971 970 0:10 / /sys/fs/selinux rw,relatime master:7 - selinuxfs selinuxfs rw
972 970 0:5 / /sys/kernel/debug rw,relatime master:8 - debugfs debugfs rw
973 970 0:14 / /sys/fs/cgroup rw,relatime master:9 - tmpfs none rw,seclabel,size=1447296k,nr_inodes=84929,mode=750,gid=1000
974 965 0:13 / /acct rw,relatime master:10 - cgroup none rw,cpuacct
975 965 0:15 / /mnt/asec rw,relatime master:11 - tmpfs tmpfs rw,seclabel,size=1447296k,nr_inodes=84929,mode=755,gid=1000
976 965 0:16 / /mnt/obb rw,relatime master:12 - tmpfs tmpfs rw,seclabel,size=1447296k,nr_inodes=84929,mode=755,gid=1000
977 965 259:8 / /system ro,relatime master:13 - ext4 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system rw,seclabel,data=ordered
978 965 259:11 / /data rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime master:14 - ext4 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata rw,seclabel,noauto_da_alloc,resuid=1000,errors=continue,data=ordered
979 965 259:5 / /sns rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime master:15 - ext4 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/sns rw,seclabel,noauto_da_alloc,errors=continue,data=ordered
980 965 259:4 / /persist-lg rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime master:16 - ext4 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/drm rw,seclabel,noauto_da_alloc,errors=continue,data=ordered
981 965 259:6 / /mpt rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime master:17 - ext4 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/mpt rw,seclabel,noauto_da_alloc,errors=continue,data=ordered
982 965 259:9 / /cache rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime master:18 - ext4 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache rw,seclabel,noauto_da_alloc,errors=continue,data=ordered
983 965 179:19 / /persist rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime master:19 - ext4 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/persist rw,seclabel,noauto_da_alloc,errors=continue,data=ordered
984 965 179:1 / /firmware ro,relatime master:20 - vfat /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/modem ro,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0337,dmask=0227,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=lower,errors=remount-ro
985 965 259:10 / /cust ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime master:21 - ext4 /dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cust ro,seclabel,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered
986 965 0:18 / /storage/emulated rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime - tmpfs tmpfs rw,seclabel,size=1447296k,nr_inodes=84929,mode=050,gid=1028
987 965 0:19 / /mnt/shell/emulated rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime master:22 - fuse /dev/fuse rw,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other
988 965 0:19 /0 /storage/emulated/legacy rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime master:22 - fuse /dev/fuse rw,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other
989 986 0:19 /0 /storage/emulated/0 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime master:22 - fuse /dev/fuse rw,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other
990 989 0:19 /obb /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime master:22 - fuse /dev/fuse rw,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other
991 986 0:19 /0 /storage/emulated/legacy rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime master:22 - fuse /dev/fuse rw,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other
```

### 992 991 0:19 /obb /storage/emulated/legacy/Android/obb rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime master:22 - fuse /dev/fuse rw,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other

Cant find than mount options of /storage/emulated/0 refuse permission changing. Or it must be politics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that emulated/0 isn't true realy file system. It's some kind of "file system emulation". Realy file system mounted as /data/0

Answer (score 5):

Since the mountpoints under /storage are managed through FUSE, they do not support permission and ownership editing.

To change permissions and/or ownership for a file stored in the internal SD, you have to navigate to /data/media/0 (provided you have root permissions), and execute chmod or chown from there. Only then will you be able to launch said script, and only from the above path.

For the external SD, follow the same procedure, but use /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1 (or the appropriate folder under /mnt/media_rw/), instead of the internal SD path.